# Where can I find a roadmap of the main bitcoin client?

Tags: client, development

Wallet encryption is long overdue, and AFAIK is coming in the next client version (0.4.0). What are the next planned milestones in the development of the main client and/or protocol? Where can I find information about that?

Comment: This question is too localised in time.  Voting to close.

Comment: Any ideas on editing this question so it is timeless?

Comment: Not really.  The closest I can think of is "does there exist a roadmap for development of the Bitcoin client?" so that the second answer can be on-topic.  Even that's not super amazing though, since the linked roadmap is basically just an email Gavin wrote in August.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, they are working on:
 - wallet encryption
 - private key import/export
 - test suite for testing bitcoin clients/libraries
 - m-of-n signature "standard transaction"

Source: [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1314666543.5889.2.camel@BMThinkPad.lan.bluematt.me&forum_name=bitcoin-development)

Answer (score 6):

You can read the [Roadmap](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAJ1JLtu7UXz2X25iWLKUUmK=oapj8OzGRH964JY=Ppzd8rOfTg@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=bitcoin-development) and the [status](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1314666543.5889.2.camel@BMThinkPad.lan.bluematt.me&forum_name=bitcoin-development) before v0.4 release

They discuss the development at
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=bitcoin-development